# fasttext pre trained models

Tags: wikipedia, fasttext

Does anyone know how often are the pre trained fasttext models available here https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/pretrained-vectors.html being updated with fresh common crawl or wikipedia data? or how old are the existing ones available for download?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall Facebook ever announcing a refresh, or intended schedule for a refresh.

The Internet Archive's Wayback Machine shows captures of that page going back to January 2018:

https://web.archive.org/web/20180104060034/https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/pretrained-vectors.html

So, absent any other claims, it'd be reasonable to assume those are at least ~4.5y old, and if fresher models required, look elsewhere or train your own on a project-relevant text corpus.

Comment: yes, that's what I thought, thank you